# Calculate the mean of a column conditioning on another column in SQL

Tags: sql

Say I have a table `test` with 3 columns, `hour`, `A`, `B`, all are ints. I want to calculate the average of A per hour (i.e. groupby `hour`) when B is greater than 0. How could I do this in SQL? Thanks.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: [Is showing effort needed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288176/is-showing-effort-needed)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select hour, avg(a)
from t
where b > 0
group by hour;
```